# using conditional from of chrome.storage.local.get is looping not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension making.I was trying to store data in local storage and retrive from it. But as I put retrieve in content script it runs that before data is saved in local storage. So I was trying to make `chrome.storage.local.get` as a conditional. To check either it works or not I have added alert. After getting into get section it generates the alert continuously. It does not go next line.I tried both quoted undefined and nonquoted undefined.

Here is my `content_script.js` code:

```
var message;

function bodyHandler(e){
    if (e.type == 'mousemove'){
        chrome.storage.local.get('word', function(data) {
            alert("from get");
            if(typeof data.word !== undefined){
                message = chrome.storage.local.get('word');
                alert("from if");
            }
            else{
                alert("from else");
                message ="Hello!";
            }
        })
        var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        for(var i=0; i < paragraph.length; i++){
            //alert('hello.');
            paragraph[i].innerHTML = message;
        }
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', bodyHandler, false);
```

Here is my popup.js:

```
var evnt = document.getElementById("clicked");

function wordGetter(){
    var txt= document.getElementById("wordinput").value;
    chrome.storage.local.set({'word': txt});
}
evnt.addEventListener('click', wordGetter);
```

I cannot understand why `alert("from get")` is running continuously.

Comment: `undefined` has to be quoted and this: `message = chrome.storage.local.get('word');` will always set `message` to `undefined`.

Comment: @Titus Do I have to write like this:  `chrome.storage.local.get('word', function(data){ message = data.word;})`

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Chrome extensions API is asynchronous so you must use the value inside a callback! More info: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: As for continuous invocation, your bodyHandler() is called on every mouse move so naturally it does just that.